# Surjectively mapping onto a generated subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and let $R'$ be the subring of $R$ generated by $\{x_i\}_{i \in I} \subseteq R$. Then $R'=\mathbb{Z}[x_i|i \in I]$. It seems like a trivial question, but can we always map a polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[\{X_i\}_{i \in I}]$ surjectively onto $R'$? I believe the answer is yes, simply because by universal property of polynomial rings there exists a unique ring homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}[\{X_i\}_{i \in I}] \to R'$ such that $\phi(X_i)=x_i$ for all $i \in I$ and since $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ generates $R'$ we have that $Im(\phi)=R^{'}$. Is this correct? Now to continue the story, it might be that there are some relations that the elements $x_i$ satisfy and so $\phi$ is not necessarily injective. Thus we can deduce that $\mathbb{Z}[\{X_i\}_{i \in I}]/J=R'$ for some ideal $J$ of $\mathbb{Z}[\{X_i\}_{i \in I}]$. Is the logic correct here?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{Z}[X_i]$ maps onto any subring generated by an $I$-tuple of elements, if you require subrings to include the identity of the ring.  (If you do not, then $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $R'=\{f(x)\in R\mid f(0)=0\}$ is a counterexample). The rest is correct.

Comment: Oh yes, subrings have the identity of the ring, thank you for pointing it out and thank you for your help @ArturoMagidin.